# POC on Cassandra and PowerBI Report server

Tags: cassandra, power-bi-report-server

1.I have been given task to set up hardware for Cassandra DB( preferably on VM). For now, Cassandra has 100 gb of data and data ingestion is at 500 bytes per every 2 seconds.What kind of hardware/VM should i use?

2. We need Power-bi Report server to connect to this DB, i plan to use  The CData ODBC Driver to establish the connection. Considering the above config will i face any issues w.r.t performance or connection?

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

To your first part:

Your incoming data rate is 250byte/s. For a single year, this is about (raw) 8GB - which is quite small and should even fit into a virtual machine. Keep in mind that your storage used on disk will be higher than this as there is overhead for internal structures as well as for replication (if you need high availability).

But I don't recommend VMs for Cassandra as they often use shared storage for their images which can be a real performance killer due to noisy neighbours and latency. This issue can be less relevant when SSDs or NVMe storage is used.

For the second part: I don't know much more from PowerBI apart from its name. But there is/was an ODBC driver for Cassandra from DataStax:

https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-datastax-odbc-driver-for-apache-cassandra

Maybe that helps.

Comment: Appreciate the response.

Comment: You can look over this article https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-planning/doc/planning/planningHardware.html - simple setups I used before ran quite well with 8GB and 4 cores. If you can just try out some setups, what could work heavily depends on how much requests you will have.

If your data is time series (inserted once and not modified, maybe with a time to live) also look at TimeWindowCompactionStrategy (SizeTieredCompationStrategy is the default).

Comment: Appreciate the response.  Any correlation between storage size and RAM + CPU ? Considering that my initial set will have 100Gb and incremental data(25B/sec) will the following hardware requirements do the job? : 500GB  and
a 64 bit CPU with 2 cores. I did check out https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-planning/doc/planning/planningHardware.html

Comment: I think it should go well, don't go too low on RAM and keep an eye on your performance metrics. Remember Cassandra is quite easy to scale if necessary.